# QML get default font height value in pixels

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols2

Is there a way to get one?

Why I need it. Here I have bad looking UI:
[Quick Controls 2 bad looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590221/quick-controls-2-bad-looking)

Here is how I can adjust checkbox size: [QML: Resize CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424852/qml-resize-checkbox)

I want `indicator.height` value to be equal to font's height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To calculate the height of the font you must use `FontMetrics`:

```
CheckBox {
    text: "CheckBox"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    checked: true

    indicator.width: indicator.height
    indicator.height: fontMetrics.height

    FontMetrics {
        id: fontMetrics
    }
}
```

[image]